# How to actually logout from a website rather than simply redirecting to login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using response.redirect facility to send the user back to login page  when he clicks the logout image button but that does not actually perform the logout operation and when user clicks the backspace button in keyboard or back button in browser the user screen gets displayed back. How to control this situation in c# asp.net and i have read some posts saying that the session should be cleared before redirecting but i dont know how to apply it in my form. I have enclosed the coding below and i request someone to help me out of this situation in a clear manner.

In Loginpage.aspx

```
protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var query = (from row in db.Logins where row.Userid == txtUname.Text && row.Password == txtPassword.Text select new { row.Userid, row.Password, row.Admin_Roll, row.Manager_Roll}).Distinct();
if (query.Count() > 0)
{
if (query.Single().Admin_Roll == 1)
{
Response.Redirect("~/HomePage.aspx");
}
else if (query.Single().Manager_Roll == 1)
{
Response.Redirect("~/DetailsPage.aspx");
}
```

and in Masperpage.master

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
}
```

Suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the you have to `clear` all Session and Cookies from you browser using C# Code.

- LogoutPage.aspx

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.Clear();
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();    
            // DO NOT REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE FROM HERE
            // REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE FROM JAVASCRIPT

        }
```

`

> and the same way you also have to clear browser `History` using javascript on page load

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        var url = window.location.href;
        window.history.go(-window.history.length);
        window.location.href = 'Login.aspx'; // REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE
    });

</script>
```

`

**Updated Answer:**
It is better to make a different Page for logout as `Logout.aspx` and write this code in `Page_Load` event of `Logout.aspx` page. And write above javascript in `<Head>` tag in `Logout.aspx` page.

Comment: You have written the code in page_load and i am using a logout image button in master page itself. Do you want me to put this code in master pageload or some other page load ...

Comment: @Ezhilan - It is better to make a different Page for logout as `Logout.aspx` and write this code in `Page_Load` event of `Logout.aspx` page. And write above javascript in `<Head>` tag in `Logout.aspx` page

Answer (score 1):

You can actively sign the person out when using forms authentication.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         // The SignOut method invalidates the authentication cookie.
         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
         Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
      }
```

SEE Microsoft reference :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288576(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**There are several ways**

Clear Your `Session` using `Session.Abandon` and use `Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");`

Then you can use Following Methods to Clear Cache or clear history

**Using Codebehind**

```
// Code disables caching by browser.
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

**Using JavaScript**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
function ClearHistory()
{
     var backlen = history.length;
     history.go(-backlen);
     window.location.href = loggedOutPageUrl
}
</SCRIPT>
```

with asp.net

without update panel

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"ClearHistory();",true);
```

with update panel

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),
Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"ClearHistory();",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx).

You can then use [SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout(v=vs.110).aspx) Method as below:-

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
```

**Edit**:

Forms authentication is used for internet web applications. If you wanna authenticate users who are not just a part of a domain (as in windows authentication) then for web apps you should go with forms authentication. This can be enabled by adding authentication mode as `Forms` in web.config file something like this:-

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="50" 
          defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

You need to read in detail about this on `MSDN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had problem with back button,below code wil diable back button when user is logged out.

```
 private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
Response.Buffer= true;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
if(Session["SessionId"] == null)
{
Response.Redirect ("Loginpage.aspx");
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also abandon their session, simply add Session.Abandon(), although the forms signout seems a more robust answer.

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
    Session.Abandon();
   Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
   }
```